# How to make an int column that must have value greater than x?

Tags: mysql

Well, basically title.

I need to create new table with few columns (that's easy), but one of them needs to make sure that inputed value is above 21 (that's hard). How can I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE myBD.myTable
        (`name` VARCHAR(90),
        `age` INT                --here I need to make sure it's above 21>,
        PRIMARY KEY (`name`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a trigger to [reject any value that does not abide by your constraint](https://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/). Two, actually: one for inserts and another for updates.

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insert_check_greater_than_21
     BEFORE INSERT ON tableName FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.fieldName <= 21
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'fieldName must be greater than 21';
          END IF;
     END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_check_greater_than_21
     BEFORE UPDATE ON tableName FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.fieldName <= 21
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'fieldName must be greater than 21';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```

This is probably not the most elegant way to define the triggers but you can read more about them in your favourite MySQL reference.

MySQL does have syntax for so-called "check constraints", [but currently ignores them](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9662/3261).